# Inserting user input to an array

Tags: arrays, input

I've had this problem with my HTML/JS file today, and I'm trying to get the script to work properly.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <h1>Pushing into an array</h1>
</head>
    <body>

    <p>Enter your input to the form before adding</p>

    <p>Click to add to array</p>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <br>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Display Variable</button>

    <form name="myform"> 
    <input type="text" name="text1" value=""> 
    <input type="button" value="Enter Value" onclick="setValue()"> 
    </form>  

    <p id="value"></p>

</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var colours = ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green"];
document.getElementById("myFunction").innerHTML = colours;

function display() {
colours.push("Blue");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = colours;
}

function setValue(){ 
var myVariable = document.forms["myform"]["text1"].value;
document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = myVariable;
}
```

The aim of this is to take the user input from the form/alert and transfer that to an array (displayed on the screen) bt I simply can't seem to get it working! Any ideas?

Comment: Is that the code actually being tested? What is the "demo" and "myFunction" elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the code sorted with help. Thanks, fixed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <script>
        var colours = ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green"];

        function display() {
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = colours;
        }

        function setValue(){ 
           var myVariable = document.myform.text1.value;
           document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = myVariable;
           colours.push(myVariable);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <p>Enter your input to the form before adding</p>

    <p>Click to add to array</p>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <br> 
    <div id="myFunction"></div>

    <button onclick="display()">Display Variable</button>

    <form name="myform"> 
    <input type="text" name="text1" value=""> 
    <input type="button" value="Enter Value" onclick="setValue()"> 
    </form>  

    <p id="demo2"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick of myFunction() probably should be display(), and document.getElementById("myFunction") doesn't currently reference an id of any element in the page, should this be 'demo' (not sure if you're trying to set the array to some element in the page or not)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to do, but from my intuition I fixed the code to do what I think you asked.

#### HTML

```
<body>

<p>Enter your input to the form before adding</p>

<p>Click to add to array</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<br> 
<div id="myFunction"></div>

<button onclick="display()">Display Variable</button>

<form name="myform"> 
<input type="text" name="text1" value=""> 
<input type="button" value="Enter Value" onclick="setValue()"> 
</form>  

<p id="value"></p>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var colours = ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green"];

function display() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = colours;
}

function setValue(){ 
   var myVariable = document.forms["myform"]["text1"].value;
   document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = myVariable;
   colours.push(myVariable);
}
```

Add a value, click **Enter value** and click **Display variable**. You'll have it listed.

Here is [the code on CodePen](http://codepen.io/ovitrif/pen/VvqpGO).